# How to insert Non-breaking space to NSString or NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

How to insert Non-breaking space (like " " in html) to NSString or NSMutableAttributedString ?

Comment: Sorry i cannot get you .. what you want ? please elaborate your question :)

Comment: Non breaking space is an HTML concept. Are you looking to add HTML escape sequences to a string of HTML code? Or do you just want to add a spine into a string? This has nothing to do with ios at all. NSString only.

Comment: Are you looking to do templating?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As Xcode treats all source code files as UTF-8 encoded text files, it should be possible to directly paste the non-breaking space into your source code:

```
NSString *text = @"100 feet long";  // non-breaking space between "100" and "feet"
```

To be on the safe side and make it more obvious, you can insert the Unicode value U+00A0 into the string:

```
NSString *text = @"100\u00a0feet long";
```

Comment: If you use `Localizable.strings`, the Unicode value should be uppercase: `"100\U00A0feet long"`.

Comment: Swift requires escaping with brackets: `\u{00a0}`.

Answer (score 1):

Swift code:

```
let text = "100\u{00A0}feet long"
```